# How do I code for an insert with a foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Q and A page on my website where it displays a question pulled from a question table in my database.  Below the question are two text boxes - one for the person's name and another for their answer, which is to be inserted into the answer table.  The answer table has a FK questionID on it and that is where I am stuck.  How do I write the script for the answer table in my code so it uses that questionID from the question table?

This is what I have so far:

```
protected void btnSubmitAnswer_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     String connectionString = "Server=root;Database=test;User=name;Password=test;";

     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionID, Answer_Name, Answer)" +
                   "VALUES (%%, '" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtAnswer.Text + "')");
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          conn.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     }
```

}

The %% is what I need fixed.  I was thinking about using a String variable but then I still don't know what I should use for that data type.

Comment: you are super open to SQL Injection, FYI

Comment: how the questions in the website is organized?

Comment: Code you've provided is not sufficient to say where you can get your questionID from. You're saying " it displays a question pulled from a question table" - so why don't pull not only question text. but also ID and then use it?

Comment: What is your model, currently you allow multiple answers for one question. One-to-many, is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, the same question can have multiple answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fetch the Question Id, you should store it into a variable in order to reuse it when inserting the command.

Like:

```
SELECT Id, /*And anything else you need*/ FROM QUESTION
```

And store it in a variable like `Int32 QuestionId;`

Also, for the sake of completeness, never concatenate SQL Strings, it makes your code vulnerable, instead use sql parameters.

```
protected void btnSubmitAnswer_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 String connectionString = "Server=root;Database=test;User=name;Password=test;";

 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
           "INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionID, Answer_Name, Answer)" +
           "VALUES (@prmQuestionId, @prmAnswerName, @prmAnswer)");
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmQuestionId", QuestionId/*HERE INSERT THE ID VALUE OF THE FETCHED QUESTION*/));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmAnswerName", txtName.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@prmAnswer", txtAnswer.Text));
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      conn.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, This will be of the most help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a get Query (Select Statement) to from the question table to retrieve the Question Id and then do an insert.

Also, use parameter strings, don't concatenate, your code can be injected with malicious behavior possibly deleting your database tables!

Comment: Thanks @AndyKorneyev removed the question and put in comment

Comment: Thanks for the warning, although I know that is true - I'm not worried about my users doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either store the id of the question in a hidden field and reference that else use an inner select within your insert statement to retrive the ID of the question.

The hidden field would be set up as below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="questionId" value="questionId" />
```

and then:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionID, Answer_Name, Answer)" +
           "VALUES (questionId.Value, '" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtAnswer.Text + "')");
```

The inner select would be in the form of

```
insert into table ((select id from questiontable where question = [the question text]), 'name', 'answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `int QuestionID` variable to hold the current `QuestionID`. Just change it when the user changes questions. You could store this in `Session`.

Side note: I recommend parameterizing `txtName.Text` and `txtAnswer.Text` to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

At the time you are getting the question for the database get the Id as well and store it somewhere.

On a side note your code is open to SQL Injection. Use parameters instead to store the values from your textboxes like this:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param.Value = txtName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Thank you for the preventative measures.

Answer (score 0):

So your control is **Gridview**, this may be the case.. Try it.

```html
protected void myRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) 
{
 String connectionString = "Server=root;Database=test;User=name;Password=test;";
  
 GridViewRow row = this.GridView1.SelectedRow; 
            int EntryID = row.RowIndex;
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
     {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionID, Answer_Name, Answer)" +
                   "VALUES (EntryID, '" + txtName.Text + "', '" + txtAnswer.Text + "')");
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          conn.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     }

  
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using a Grid View to display the questions.

Comment: This will actually be very useful as well, thanks :)